# Timestamp server rfc3161 response token generation in Python

Tags: python, m2crypto, trusted-timestamp, timestamping, rfc3161

I'm trying to implement tsa server on python using twisted. Currently I'm using openssl binary to generate response, but this seems ugly to me, that's why I'm trying to figure out how to make response token with m2crypto.

Thanks in advance for help!

Maris.

**EDITED:**

how to achieve with m2crypto?:

```
openssl ts -reply -section tsa_config1 -queryfile query.tsq -out response.tsr
```

Comment: http://svn.osafoundation.org/m2crypto/trunk/doc/howto.ssl.html

Answer (score 1):

M2Crypto does not yet wrap those pieces of openssl, so you can't use M2Crypto for what you are using the openssl command line client for.

Answer (score 0):

You may be also interested in [PyASN1](http://pyasn1.sourceforge.net/) project, however, I should admit there's no adequate library to implement RFC3161 functionality in Python today. I would look towards Perl instead.